# STM32MP157F dmaengine: dmaengine_prep_dma_memcpy works, dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic does not

Tags: stm32, dma

​
We have implemented our custom driver that uses DMA to copy a large amount of data from the FMC interface (an FPGA mapped to it) to the RAM using the STM32 mdma engine with 32 dma channels. The FPGA contains a small FIFO we want to copy the data from.
​
For very fast data acquisition the setup time for new DMA transactions becomes critical!

The first implementation used a workqueue to create the next DMA transaction. It could not be done directly from the "dma_completed" atomic context though some necessary IO that has to wait. This lead to pauses between DMA transaction up to 5ms and buffer overflows in the FPGAs FIFO.

As I am copying from a memory mapped region to RAM, I am using `dmaengine_prep_dma_memcpy`.

**I implemented a number of improvements that reduced the pause betweens DMAs:**

- I am fusing dma mapped pages so that less dma transaction entries have to be created so less dma engine programming is necessary.
- I am preparing the next dma pages upfront. So the next DMA transaction can be directly started from the "dma_completed" routine.
- I am using a second dma channel and toggle between them when dma_completed is called. This allows to setup a second DMA with the first one still running. *Though linux dma api allows this with one channel, the MDMA engine does not and ignores the added transactions.*

**Usually the pause is now lower than 1ms.** But there a spikes were the FIFO nearly overflowing.

Finally I tried to use `dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic`. This would be perfect. A continuously running DMA with no need for a setup time between interrupts.

​**But this does not work**. Or better: I do not get it to work...

The transaction created with `dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic` does not want to start!
I am getting a new dma_cookie and any status request to the channel returns "DMA_IN_PROGRESS". It never completes and the completetion callback is also never called.
Though `dmaengine_prep_dma_memcpy` works fine...

I think this is because of the difference between software vs hardware triggered DMA transactions.

Looking into `stm32-mdma.c` is see that `dmaengine_prep_dma_memcpy` has its own setup routine whereas `dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic` use `stm32_mdma_set_xfer_param()` that always configures a HW request.

**My very big big questions:**

Is there a way to use dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic for a MEMORY to MEMORY DMA transaction (software triggered)? This would be the perfect solution to my performance problem...

​Are we missing some signals to connect the FPGA to the SOC? My FPGA programming collegue suspects some missing TSEL (trigger selection) setting. He suspects `dmaengine_prep_dma_cyclic` will work then.

If a minimum driver module source code example would help in getting better answers, I can provide one in short time. Please note that this is highly hardware specific. Other SOCs than STM32MP157F may have different behaviour.

Thanks for every feedback!

Bye Gunther

References:

https://wiki.st.com/stm32mpu/wiki/Dmaengine_overview

https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/linux/blob/v5.15-stm32mp/drivers/dma/stm32-mdma.c